# Manipulate silverlight visual tree from webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, wpf, xaml, silverlight

I have a webpage with a silverlight application that is not mine. 
I want to add a new button to the app or to make an existing button behave diffrently. 
I know I can achive this effect using wpf and snoop.  But is there a way to do this using js on Silverlight app running in webpage?

Comment: Depends, are they [RegisteredScriptableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlpage.registerscriptableobject(v=vs.95).aspx)'s and is it SL5? You mention it's not yours so I'm going to assume not. Would be neat to see if anyone knows any tricks though. Although it sounds like something that could be used for shady purposes if it was easy to do.

Comment: I need this for very unshady purposes. to allow integration with my product 0 code added from my clients side.
in regular html/css its very easy.
thanks for the advice il check this out in the morning.

can I perhaps read the visual tree without manipulating it?
for example find the text in all buttons?